# rolling sum to calculate YTD for each month group by product and save to separate columns using SQL

Tags: sql, window-functions

I have a data like this:

```
Order_No  Product Month   Qty
3001       r33     1       8
3002       r34     1       11
3003       r33     1       17
3004       r33     2       3
3005       r34     2       11
3006       r34     3       1
3007       r33     3       -10
3008       r33     3       18
```

I'd like to calculate total YTD qty for product and each month and save to separate columns. Below is what I want

```
Product  Qty_sum_jan    Qty_sum_feb    Qty_sum_mar
  r33         25              28             36
  r34         11              22             23
```

I know how to use window function to calculate rolling sums but I have no idea to group them to separate columns. I currently use something like this:

```
case when Month = 1 then sum(Qty) over(partition by Product order by Month) else 0 end as Qty_sum_jan,
case when Month <=2 then sum(Qty) over(partition by Product order by Month) else 0 end as Qty_sum_feb,
case when Month <=3 then sum(Qty) over(partition by Product order by Month) else 0 end as Qty_sum_mar,
```

This will get me rolling sum by order but how to get to product level like what I show above? If I use group by then it will throw an error since Month is not in group by clause. I also cannot just use max to get the last value since qty can be negative so the last value may not be maximum. I use sparkSQL by the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my understanding, there is no need to use window functions. The following query achieves your desired output:

```sql
select
    product,
    sum(case when month = 1 then qty else 0 end) as sum_qty_jan,
    sum(case when month <= 2 then qty else 0 end) as sum_qty_feb,
    sum(case when month <= 3 then qty else 0 end) as sum_qty_mar
from your_table
group by 1;
```

**Output:**

| product | sum_qty_jan | sum_qty_feb | sum_qty_mar |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| r33 | 25 | 28 | 36 |
| r34 | 11 | 22 | 23 |

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess I made myself stuck in window function